# Backface culling has weird glitch (Squares wont show up from culling)

Tags: modeling

So I like to use backface culling when I make my cars to showcase the topology. When I turn backface culling on though, it doesn't show any squares in on the backfaces. Instead they just disappear. On the first picture is how it looks currently. On the second picture it explains how the squares would look with a drawing. Thank you for your time!

[image].[image: Picture 1]